# stream_set_timeout not working for ssh2_exec in PHP

Tags: php, ssh, stream, timeout

I am having trouble when try to set timeout for my `ssh2_exec` connection in PHP, so that when there is something wrong when running the command, it will release the executing thread and will not jam the whole web site. I have tried `stream_set_timeout($stream,$seconds)` but it seems not to work as expected.

Is there any ideas on this?

```
//run specified command (ssh)
    function runCMD($cmd){
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($this->conn, $cmd )))
        {
            echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
            fclose($stream);
            return ERROR_SSH_EXEC_COMM;
        }

        sleep(1);
        stream_set_timeout($stream,5);//>>not work
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $res = stream_get_contents($stream);

        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the code to the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP ssh2\_connect() Implement A Timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730556/php-ssh2-connect-implement-a-timeout)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering how to set the timeout, there's a [default_socket_timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) variable in php.ini that can be used to set the timeout for any socket-based connections in your current session.

You can check it by simply running

```php
$timeStart = time();
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 5);
$ssh = ssh2_connect('123.123.123.123');
echo (time() - $timeStart), PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do that with [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->setTimeout(5);
echo $ssh->exec('whatever');
?>
```

If you want to execute subsequent commands after that one you'll need to do `$ssh->reset()`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, There are no true 'timeout' implementations in the php ssh2 specs.

The only solution that I have found for this problem can be found in this post here:
[PHP ssh2_connect() Implement A Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730556/php-ssh2-connect-implement-a-timeout/12521433)